# Java - Event handle data protection for Strings with 2 data types

Tags: java

For event handling how can you check a string that has a combination of integers and a character?

For example - 1234p

If the user enters the example above, how can you check if the user enters integers first and then a character at the end? What kind of exception will be thrown if the data type input is not an integer or char?

Answer (score 1):

You can use REGEX `[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]` to match if the string contains chars and integers otherwise throw an IllegalArgumentException

```
public void check(String input) {
    if (!input.matches("[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]")) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid string");
    }
    // do other logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to target specific characters? Like 'a' or 'Z'

Comment: yes this possible

Comment: above regex start withy any digits one or more and any character from a-z and A-Z

Comment: I have it working kind of, can I target specifically only 'a' and 't' for example. If it was any other letter, the exception would be thrown

Comment: Try this REGEX "[0-9]+[a|t]"

Comment: Yes. Ex 1234t, targeting only 1-4 numbers in front of the string and targeting 'a' or 't'. Is it possible with genex?

Comment: This one "[0-9]{1,4}[a|t]" will match (one or two or three or four digits) then (a or t)

Comment: I'm able to get it working. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

So from your question it sounds like you expect a string that has all numbers except the last character that has to be an alphabet. You can check if the given string matches this condition the following way too:

```
String string = "1234p";
int length = string.length();
boolean numsFirst = string.substring(0, length - 1).chars().allMatch(x -> Character.isDigit(x));
boolean lastChar = Character.isDigit(string.charAt(length - 1));
if(numsFirst && lastChar)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```